# Mac: What is PKL folder on Mac?

Tags: mac, osx-lion

So i want to clean up my computer by finding big folders on an Application called GrandPerspective and i delete un-necessary  folder in directory `~/Library/Application support/`, and i found a folder called `PKL` and i realized the `PKL` folder recorded all i typed and screen-shot my computer without i screen-shot, and also it recorded all page that i visited

Note: `PKL` folder size is 2,2 GB (Gigabyte) with 5 items

What is `PKL` folder?, is it safe to delete it?

Comment: It sounds like spyware. Before you delete it, you should probably do a full backup of your system for forensics purposes. Then see if you can determine what process(es) are accessing that folder, so you can find and delete the spyware. If you delete that folder without first ridding your system of the spyware, the spyware will probably create another folder with a similar name and keep spying on you.

Comment: Oh, but is PKL folder dangerous?, i mean like is that folder sent to people who set the spyware on my mac?, or is PKL folder already on Mac before?

Comment: Nothing in `~/Library/Application support/` is there by default. All contents are made by some app or another. Strictly speaking, throwing away any folder in there will only potentially break any app that created it - but then you need to check back & see if it gets re-created. You should at least run Malwarebytes, especially as you are running an extremely old, out-dated & insecure OS.

Comment: Oh ok, Thanks for that, i will check my Applications that i have